# Problems working with .dae files

Tags: ros, rviz, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, dae

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm struggling with a urdf model to visualize in rviz, this is the file I've written so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="bot2489">

  <material name="black">
    <color rgba = "0 0 0 1"/>
  </material>

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="black"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bot2489_description/meshes/bot2489_body.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bot2489_description/meshes/bot2489_body.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
</robot>
```

The problem is that when I launch it in rviz, using the `urdf_tutorial display.launch` file, nothing appears.
In the "Global Status" section of the window there's a warning :

```
No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [base_link] does not exist
```

It is weird, because the .dae file should be fine (is made with Rhino v5 and saved as .dae), and on the terminal, while loading the file, I get no errors.
Can you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276841/problems-working-with-.dae-files/) by [SteBisi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32697/stebisi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-29**:
Can you update your question text with the *exact* command that you use to start everything (ie: the one with `display.launch`) and include the *complete* output you see on the console after starting it?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-11-29**:
If you posted your complete URDF, I think the issue is that you don't have any `<joint>` elements. Without a joint connecting two links, there is nothing for the `robot_state_publisher` to send on `/tf`. Try adding a link with only the `name` set, and a fixed joint connecting the two links

**Comment by [SteBisi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32697/stebisi/) on 2017-11-29**:
@jarvisschultz, I think it t could be also that, but I got the same error even after adding the joints.
Ended up that the problem were the .dae files, that I created with rhino.I just had to export them to Blender as .3ds files and there export them as .dae files and everything worked

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-30**:
It would perhaps be good to see what the incompatibility is. Could you perhaps submit an issue to [ros-visualization/rviz/issues](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues) with a minimal URDF and an example Collada file that shows this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try adding inertial before the ,, this way

```
  <inertial>
    <mass value="1.0" />
    <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0" />
  </inertial>
```

More accurate inertial can be from the CAD software itself.
Also, often the mesh (*.dae or *.stl ) from CAD software will be in millimeters. So you might also need to scale the dimensions by 0.001 this way

---

Originally posted by [avcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/32795/avcx/) with karma: 26 on 2017-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SteBisi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32697/stebisi/) on 2017-11-29**:
Thank you for the answer, I tried to do what you said but I still ave the same problem